# How to have both 'get by id' and 'get by name' routes on ASP.NET core 2.0 controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, api-design

I'm writing a small Web API controller. Currently I've routed a

```
[HttpGet("{id}"}]
```

path and it works fine: localhost:8080/Controller/1 returns the item with the id equal to 1.

The problem is that I am trying to add a 'get by name' request:

```
[HttpGet("{name}")]
```

How can I go about doing this?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking.. you want two GET requests in the same class?

Comment: Basically I wanted to have 2 GET requests on the same controller route. One that receives a string and another that receives a integer. The problem is now solved by the answer below, sorry I couldn't be clearer with phrasing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this exact example you can put in a route constraint indicating that `id` is an int.  It should route correctly after that.

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public string GetById(int id)
{
   return id.ToString();
}

[HttpGet("{name}")]
public string GetByName(string name)
{
   return name + " name";
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Works perfectly.

Comment: Why I see the next error: HttpGetAttribute does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument? I'm using web api application.